# If array length = value, then do something C#

Tags: c#, arrays, split

I have an array that I call from SQL and has , (commas) in it. I want to populate a excel with it. However, sometimes the array has no values, 1 value, 2 .....up to 5 values (i.e. , commas). So I am trying to separate it into a separate variable based on the length of the array.

```
string[] BeneficiaryFullName1 = ex.BeneficiaryFullName1.Split(' ');

if (BeneficiaryFullName1 != null || 
    BeneficiaryFullName1.Length >= 0 && 
    BeneficiaryFullName1.Length < 1)
{
    ex.BeneficiaryFullName1 = BeneficiaryFullName1[0];
}

if (BeneficiaryFullName1 != null || 
    BeneficiaryFullName1.Length >= 0 && 
    BeneficiaryFullName1.Length < 2)
{
    ex.BeneficiaryFullName1 = BeneficiaryFullName1[0];
    ex.BeneficiaryFullName2 = BeneficiaryFullName1[1];
}
```

However, I am not getting it right. When there is "" empty return it keeps going to the second if statement and gives an error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check [Array.Length](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.length?view=net-6.0) property. If its 0, the array has no values

Comment: Show us the **actual values** of those properties.

Comment: What is `ex`, exactly?

Comment: Your checks for null are not required. If the input string to split is not null then you have at least one element (Length == 1) in the resulting array even if there is no space to split the input.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `BeneficiaryFullName1 != null` (which is *redundant*) and `BeneficiaryFullName1.Length < ...` (which is *erroneous*: if we have a name with, say, `4` words we can and should take first two of them):

```
// We want at most 3 items, empty ones (e.g. trailing spaces) removed
string[] BeneficiaryFullName1 = ex.BeneficiaryFullName1.Split(
  ' ', 3, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

// If we have at least 2 items, take the 2nd
if (BeneficiaryFullName1.Length >= 2)
  ex.BeneficiaryFullName2 = BeneficiaryFullName1[1];

// If we have at least 1 item, take the 1st
if (BeneficiaryFullName1.Length >= 1)
  Bex.BeneficiaryFullName2 = BeneficiaryFullName1[0];
```

Comment: Thanks, i got it working

Comment: @ShaunWeinberg, consider accepting it as the answer if it did indeed solve your problem.